# Influencing order of operations in CSS selectors

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

In maths you are able to influence order of operations using `( )` is there anything like that in CSS that would enable me to make this selector work

```
( .wrapper > input:not(:blank) ) + .placeholder {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```css
.placeholder {
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="text" required>
</div>
<div class="placeholder"></div>
```

Comment: No since it requires a parent selector which does not exist.

Comment: No, but even if it did and by analogy with Maths notation, the bit in parentheses would .still select the input in your example, given the (seemingly current) definition of :blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no, there's not. CSS traverses downwards, hence the name, ***Cascading*** *Style Sheets* (also due in part to the fact that CSS renders as its written, and later declaration override early ones higher in a file.) Given the nature of CSS, you cannot traverse upwards in the DOM under any circumstances.

Although not fully supported by all browser, the [`:has()` pseudo-selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) is slowly being integrated. The `:has()` pseudo selector can be used to check for children without traversing downwards.

Comment: not correct. There is a parent selector: `has()`. The thing is, that it is only supported by Safari and Chrome desktop so far. Firefox rushing the implementation atm.

Comment: @tacoshy As the `:has()` pseudo-selector isn't fully supported by the current spec, I hadn't mentioned it. I've edited my answer accordingly.